# Algorithm to get (-2) based binary bits

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

I want to know the good algorithm to get the (-2) based binary bits for the specific number.

So let me define what (-2) based binary bits.
The bits is the array of binary element of 1 or 0.
The number `K` represented by this `N` length bits `A` is calculated following:

```
K = A[0] * (-2 ^ 0) + A[1] * (-2 ^ 1) + A[2] * (-2 ^ 2) + ... +  + A[N-1] * (-2 ^ (N-1))
```

So for example, the bits `00011` represents the number `8` because

```
1*(-2^4) + 1*(-2^3) + 0*(-2^2) + 0*(-2^1) + 0*(-2^0)
```

So the question is when the number is defined, what is the good algorithm to calculate shortest bits explained above.

Comment: Check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643731/806919

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base) shows this surprising method:

```
unsigned int toNegaBinary(unsigned int value) // input in standard binary
{
    unsigned int Schroeppel2 = 0xAAAAAAAA; // = 2/3*((2*2)^16-1) = ...1010
    return (value + Schroeppel2) ^ Schroeppel2; // eXclusive OR
    // resulting unsigned int to be interpreted as string of elements ε {0,1} (bits)
}
```