# Convert n into negative base form in Swift 3

Tags: algorithm, swift3

Okay, so I'm fully well aware of how this is applied in C# and C. But I can't figure it out in Swift 3.

Is there an algorithm to convert n into negabinary base (-2).

```
 7 = -3*-2 + 1  (least significant digit)
-3 =  2*-2 + 1
 2 = -1*-2 + 0
-1 =  1*-2 + 1
 1 =  0*-2 + 1  (most significant digit)
```

Comment: Hi! the following link might be helpful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637781/calculating-the-negabinary-representation-of-a-given-number-without-loops

Comment: Where did you get stuck?